# Snap View check through javascript

Tags: javascript, windows-8

How can I check using JavaScript whether snapview is functioning or not .

```
var SNAPPED_VIEW = 320;

window.addEventListener("resize", onViewStateChanged);

function onViewStateChanged(eventArgs) {
    var viewStates = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState, msg;
    var newViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value;
    if (newViewState === viewStates.snapped) {
        var msg = new Windows.UI.Popups.MessageDialog("snap view mode");
    } else if (newViewState === viewStates.filled) {
        showMenu('filled');
    } else if (newViewState === viewStates.fullScreenLandscape) {
        showMenu('landscape');
    } else if (newViewState === viewStates.fullScreenPortrait) {
        //Currently not supported
    }
}
```

Using this code I am trying to do, but it is showing undefined when using break point.

Comment: what specifically is undefined?  your dialog won't really do anything because you're not displaying it, but the code you have seems to work correctly for me just by dropping it into default.js.

Answer (score 1):

I recently came up with a solution. It is not Windows 8 app specific, so it doesn't require `Windows.UI`.

http://menacingcloud.com/?c=targetSnapMode

When combined with the `@viewport` declaration, it makes for an effective combo.

```
@-ms-viewport { width: device-width; } @viewport { width: device-width; }
```

The above `@viewport` declaration is discussed at http://menacingcloud.com/?c=cssViewportOrMetaTag

Answer (score 0):

Just as Jim said your code works perfectly fine but you're not displaying your dialog. I just added a text box and assigned values for the different views and it works perfectly fine:

```
var SNAPPED_VIEW = 320;

window.addEventListener("resize", onViewStateChanged);

function onViewStateChanged(eventArgs) {
   var viewStates = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationViewState, msg;
   var newViewState = Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ApplicationView.value;
   if (newViewState === viewStates.snapped) {
    document.getElementById("screenMode").innerText = "s";
   } else if (newViewState === viewStates.filled) {
    document.getElementById("screenMode").innerText = "f";
   } else if (newViewState === viewStates.fullScreenLandscape) {
    document.getElementById("screenMode").innerText = "l"
   } else if (newViewState === viewStates.fullScreenPortrait) {
    //Currently not supported
   }
}
```

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="screenMode"/>
```